# how to change user&password dialog text in OS X?

Tags: install4j

There is "Request privileges" dialog box in OX S.

[image]

There is "install4j을(를) 변경해야 합니다. ~~~~~"

I want to change text "product name" instead of "install4j"

how to change user&password dialog text in OS X ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an OS X developer, but I understand the text for the authentication dialog is retrieved from the installer app's metadata. I'm guessing that you're using install4j and want to customise the user's experience.

However I found a few pages when googling for "install4j os x installer name". Try checking this page out: http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/context/Context.html

Comment: thank you for your response. I have already seen this page. but I don't solve it